# How do I handle bad input (entering non numerical values)?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def calc_area(radius):
    return (radius **2) * (math.pi)

def calc_circ (radius):
    return (math.pi * radius) * 2

radius = float(input('Please enter the cirlcle\'s radius: '))
print ('The area of the the circle is', calc_area(radius), 'and the circumference is', calc_circ(radius))
```

What can i do to make sure the user does not type a letter?

Answer (score 1):

Before making any calculations, try checking users input to make sure that they submitted a number.

```
try:
   value = int(userInput)
except ValueError:
   print("That's not an int!")
```

Or in your case:

```
def calc_area(radius):
    return (radius **2) * (math.pi)

def calc_circ (radius):
    return (math.pi * radius) * 2

try:
    radius = float(input('Please enter the cirlcle\'s radius: '))
    print ('The area of the the circle is', calc_area(radius), 'and the circumference is', calc_circ(radius))
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use try catch also!

```
ip = input('Please enter the cirlcle\'s radius: ')
if isinstance(ip, int):
    temp = float(ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the assert statement

```
def calc_area(radius):
    assert isinstance(radius, int) or isinstance(radius, float), "Radius must be a number."
    return (radius **2) * (math.pi)
```

When the user tries to pass in something other than a number, they get this:

```
>>> calc_area("a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    calc_area("a")
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 2, in calc_area
    assert isinstance(radius, int) or isinstance(radius, float), "Radius must be a number."
AssertionError: Radius must be a number.
```

Nice for being able to add try/catch statements if you use the code later, the other answers are better for just interacting with a simple user though.